# Why Kibana not listening port 5061?

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, kibana

I facing an issue very strange due to others issues found in other threads not happening exactly the same than me.

Well, Elastic work as a service and Kibana working as a service and checked both witn: **service xxxxx status**.

When i check which port are listening with netstat -natp, display:

[image]

[image]

As can be seen, the service is up and running, but not listening...

I can not figure out whats happening. 
Any help?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Kibana.yml

[image]

Executing command "journalctl -u kibana -f":

[image]

Comment: Do you have any error in the kibana log or in `/var/log/messages` ? Also share your configs for elastticsearch an kibana.

Comment: Please share your `kibana.yml`

Comment: @leandrojmp the kibana error.log is empty

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ Updated post showing the only two lines uncommented from such config file.

Comment: Find out what Kibana is doing by: strace -p <kibana_pid>

Comment: @BjarteBrandt yes, there's must be a problem due to once executed such command, Kibana exit with exit-code 1

Comment: What is systemd saying about the situation?: sudo journalctl -u kibana -f

Comment: @BjarteBrandt It fails and trying to guess the error in /var/log/kibana/kibana.log but empty. Do not know what kind of error arises! Updated the post showning the exit of such command.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt now i see a "mapper_parsing_exception": No handler for type [flattered] declared on field [state]

Comment: That should probably be `[flattened]` instead. The whole error message is present in your journalctl command, but it's further up in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least i could solved the issue. the problem was that I was installing elasticsearch-oss instead of the default elasticsearch.

Once uninstalled elasticsearch-oss and installed the default elasticsearch, kibana started working fine!